# How to annotate Python list with variable length

Tags: python, annotations

How do I write the annotation for either Python list with variable length or None?

As I write like this, it returns an error.

```py
def some_function(params: list[str, ...])  # this gives error: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`


def some_function(params: List[str, ...])  # this also gives error: TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got Ellipsis.
```

Comment: Lists are inherently variable length.  `list[str]` means "a list of one or more strings."  Isn't that enough?

Comment: @JohnGordon should that be "zero or more"? Wouldn't `[]` pass a type checker?

Comment: In case your list might contain different objects then you could import Any from the *typing* module and declare *x: list[Any]*. A list can only have one type argument unlike, for example, tuples

Comment: @Mark Honestly I don't know.  I assume that an empty list would need a different type hint.  But I have very little experience with type hinting, so I could be wrong.

Comment: it seems that list[str] means a list of one or more str type. 
list[str] and List[str] can be used interchangeably.
If we want to allow None, one way is `List[Union[str, None]]`

So, I was looking for the last expression. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear how `List[Union[str, None]]` relates to your question. This allows a list like `[None]` which is a list with one element not an empty list. `list[str] means a list of one or more str type`  I don't think this is correct. See the first example in [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/) showing  `primes: List[int] = []` suggesting an empty list is a valid `List[int]`. It makes sense since a lot of code consumes values until a list is empty or starts with empty lists and appends. It would be really cumbersome if the typing complained here.

Comment: I am not asking for further comment here. Can you suggest an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`List[str]` and `list[str]` can interchangeably used. List is from typing module, so the `List[str]` is probably more favorable for the annotation.

This means, list of variable length including an empty list.

List[Union[str, None]] is different. this means, list can contain None, so like this; list[None, 'hello'].